# Bind record to another entity

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, easyadmin

I have a blog with posts. There is a field blog.creator = user.id. Accordingly, there are two entities. I want that when creating an entry in the blog table, the id of the authorized user is put in the blog.creator field.

how to do it CORRECTLY?

Question 1:
if I create a form myself and handle it, then I want to do this on form validation:

```php
class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
    private $security;
    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $blog  = new Blog();
        $form    = $this->createForm(BlogType::class, $blog);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $blog->setCreatorId($this->security->getUser()->getId());

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager();
            $em->persist($blog);
            $em->flush();
```

Is it correct? or is there a magic solution?

Question 2:
I installed EasyAdminBundle, which works very well, makes it easy to view Blog posts, edit and add them.
How should I configure so that the `creator` field is set by `id` authorized user?
I think, the answer should have been written in https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html, but for some reason did not find anything there or in other sections.
There is a feeling that this should be done through the supply of options that will be passed to createFormBuilder:

```
# config/packages/easy_admin.yaml
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Customer:
            class: App\Entity\Customer
            form:
                form_options: { validation_groups: ['Default', 'my_validation_group'] }
    # ...
```

```php
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity, array(
    'data_class' => 'App\Entity\Customer',
    'validation_groups' => array('Default', 'my_validation_group'),
))
-> ...
```

but what I must set in these options? if possible, point to the right place in the documentation then.
Or should I define auto-completion of this field when creating an entity (in an entity class)? But then I’ll bind the entity with a functional, which seems to be not permissible

my Entities
User

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements UserInterface
{
```

Blog

```php
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Blog.php

namespace App\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\User;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository\BlogRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Blog
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $creator_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="creator_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
...
    /**
     * Set creator_id
     * @param integer $creator_id
     * @return Blog
     */
    public function setCreatorId($creator_id)
    {
        $this->creator_id = $creator_id;
        $this->setUser();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get creator_id
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCreatorId()
    {
        return $this->creator_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user.
     * @param integer $creator_id
     * @return Blog
     */
    private function setUser()
    {
        if(empty($this->creator_id)) {
            $this->user = new User();
        } elseif($this->em && !empty($this->creator_id)) {
            $this->user = $this->em->getRepository('User')->find($this->creator_id);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user.
     * @return \App\Entity\User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     * @ORM\PostPersist
     */
    public function fetchEntityManager(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        if(is_null($this->em)) {
            $this->em = $args->getEntityManager();
        }
        if(is_null($this->user)) {
            $this->setUser();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Great news! Finally, somebody showed me the right place for the documentation
[documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html).
there is always a lack of a detailed example or to poke a person into a specific place in the documentation

Now everything is simple:
field in table blog.creator_id,
property in entity:

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     */
    protected $creator;
```

controller:

```php
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $blog  = new Blog();
        $form    = $this->createForm(BlogType::class, $blog);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $blog->setCreator($this->getUser());

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager();
            $em->persist($blog);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('BloggerBlogBundle_blog_show', array(
                    'id'    => $blog->getId()))
            );
        }

        return $this->render('@BloggerBlog/Blog/form.html.twig', array(
            'form'    => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```